# Get info about monitors, keyboards and mice connected to computer

Tags: c#, get, product, device

Is there an effective method to get product name, manufacturer, some unique ID or something like that of monitors, keyboards and mice connected to computer in c#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394582%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for that, you can find examples here :

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7365/Retrieving-Hardware-Information-in-C

Comment: And since you taged with C#, check out this MSDN library that provides an interface in C# to access the WMI namespaces. http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/NitoWMI

Comment: That is it! Thanks. But one more thing now I use Win32_DesktopMonitor for monitor, Win32_Keyboard for keyboard but there isn't Win32_Mouse. How do I require informations about mouse?

Comment: It was Win32_PointingDevice

Answer (score 0):

For get information about monitor you can use OpenSource Project (https://sourceforge.net/projects/wmimonitor/) is a simple WMI Provider written in C# (.NET 3.5 SP1 is required) to list the Serial Number and Model name of the attached Monitor(s).**
or use this code

```
try
        {
            ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = 
                new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", 
                "SELECT * FROM Win32_DesktopMonitor"); 

            foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
                Console.WriteLine("Win32_DesktopMonitor instance");
                Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
                Console.WriteLine("Description: {0}", queryObj["Description"]);
            }
        }
        catch (ManagementException e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("An error occurred while querying for WMI data: " + e.Message);
        }
```

For get information about mic have a look at the open source .NET [Voice Recorder](http://voicerecorder.codeplex.com/) project which uses [NAudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com/).or see this [artilce](http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/articles/NET-Voice-Recorder),
For get keboard information use this [sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CCS-LABS-WMI-Getting-bc106fa2)